# How to make UITableview scroll when dragged cell reached at the top or bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, uiscrollview

Basically, my goal is

1. To create two table views side by side and by scrolling one other tableview should also scroll.
2. One of the tableview should possess a drag and drop cell functionally.
3. When we drag cell and it reaches the top or bottom other table view content must be scrolled to (Both table views together)
   I have assembled this code that worked for the first two points but I am unable to achieve the 3rd point.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightTableView: UITableView!
    
    var dragInitialIndexPath: IndexPath?
    var dragCellSnapshot: UIView?
    
    var arr1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R"]
    var arr2 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer:)))
        self.rightTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)

    }
    
    @objc func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let longpress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
        let state = longpress.state
        let locationInView = longpress.location(in: self.rightTableView)
        let indexPath = self.rightTableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)
        switch state {
        case .began:
            if indexPath != nil {
                Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
                let cell = self.rightTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! SecondTableViewCell
                My.cellSnapShot = snapshopOfCell(inputView: cell)
                var center = cell.center
                My.cellSnapShot?.center = center
                My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
                self.rightTableView.addSubview(My.cellSnapShot!)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    center.y = locationInView.y
                    My.cellSnapShot?.center = center
                    My.cellSnapShot?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
                    My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.98
                    cell.alpha = 0.0
                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    if finished {
                        cell.isHidden = true
                    }
                })
            }

        case .changed:
            var center = My.cellSnapShot?.center
            center?.y = locationInView.y
            My.cellSnapShot?.center = center!
            
            if ((indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != Path.initialIndexPath)) {

                self.arr2.swapAt((indexPath?.row)!, (Path.initialIndexPath?.row)!)
                self.rightTableView.moveRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!, to: indexPath!)
                Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
            }

        default:
            if let cell = self.rightTableView.cellForRow(at: Path.initialIndexPath!) as? SecondTableViewCell{
                cell.isHidden = false
                cell.alpha = 0.0
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    My.cellSnapShot?.center = cell.center
                    My.cellSnapShot?.transform = .identity
                    My.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
                    cell.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                    if finished {
                        Path.initialIndexPath = nil
                        My.cellSnapShot?.removeFromSuperview()
                        My.cellSnapShot = nil
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    func snapshopOfCell(inputView: UIView) -> UIView {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        inputView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let cellSnapshot : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
        cellSnapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cellSnapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
        cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: 0.0)
        cellSnapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        return cellSnapshot
    }

    struct My {
        static var cellSnapShot: UIView? = nil
    }

    struct Path {
        static var initialIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil
    }

}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr1.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if tableView == leftTableView{
            let cell = leftTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! FirstTableViewCell
            cell.firstLabel.text = arr1[indexPath.row]
            return cell
            
        }else{
            let cell = rightTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as! SecondTableViewCell
            cell.secondLabel.text = arr2[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == leftTableView {
            rightTableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
            rightTableView.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
            
        } else {
            leftTableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
            leftTableView.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in swift haven't done much code. If someone guides me on how I can achieve the 3rd point it will be a great favor. If someone suggests some other way to achieve these goals then most welcome.

Comment: When you drag a cell to the bottom, does its table view scroll and the other does not? That's the problem, right?

Comment: when I drag a cell at the top and try to push so the table view can scroll it show me uneven behaviour (that table view start scrolling infinitely) + other table does not scroll together